# f is even or odd, prove that f^2 is even

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to verify whether a statement is correct or false. The statement is as following: If the function *f* is either odd or even, then the function *f^2* is even.

To my understanding, the statement is correct. However, I'm really struggling with the proof.

Comment: Is $f^2(x) = (f(x))^2$ or $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$? (Amusingly enough the statement is true for both!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$f(x)=\pm f(-x) \implies f^2(x) = f^2(-x)$$

Comment: The OP is obviously a beginner to proof writing. They should perhaps do it by cases rather than like this.

Comment: Thank you, so simple once you see it.

Answer (score 1):

Proof: If $f(x)$ is odd, then $f(-x)=-f(x)$. So $f^2(-x)=[-f(x)]^2=f^2(x)$.

If $f(x)$ is even, then $f(-x)=f(x)$. So $f^2(-x)=[f(x)]^2=f^2(x)$.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation. your answer combined with Macavity's really made it click for me.

Comment: @user1904218 No problem!